# How to interact between ev3 and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-4

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4B, and I think it will be nice to connect it to my old LEGO EV3 hub so I can used the EV3's mentors and sensors. I plan is to make Raspberry Pi send messages to the EV3 hub to make the mentors move, and the EV3 hub send messages to Raspberry Pi about information from the sensors. But I don't know how to do it, can you tell me how? I don't care it will be a wired connection or Bluetooth or WIFI, and it will be better if I don't have to install a new operating system on my EV3, but it's OK if I have to. Thank you very much!

Comment: A quick google seemed to find the answer: https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/getting-started/ . There is also this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/legomindstormsev3/ref/controlling-lego-mindstorms-ev3-robot-using-raspberry-pi-sense-hat.html

Comment: You can also take a look at brickpi: https://www.dexterindustries.com/brickpi/